# How can I import 1000 data into postgresql with python?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I've some code to input data into list, how can I import data in my list into database?

```
import psycopg2
import random
import string
import time

conn = psycopg2.connect(host="localhost",database="postgres", user="postgres", password="potatona1")
cursor = conn.cursor()

FullChar = 'CEFLMPRTVWXYK0123456789#'
total = 4
count = 10
count = int(count)


for i in range(1000):
    for x in range(total): 
        unique_code = ''.join(random.sample(FullChar, count - 1)) + '#'
        unique_code = ''.join(random.sample(unique_code, len(unique_code)))

        list(unique_code)

        postgres_insert_query = """ INSERT INTO employees (id_employee, name) VALUES (%s,%s)"""
        record_to_insert = (1, unique_code)
        cursor.execute(postgres_insert_query, record_to_insert)
        conn.commit()
        count = cursor.rowcount
        print (count, "Record inserted successfully into mobile table")
```

I want import 1000 data to postgresql with python.

Comment: Welocome to stackoverflow! Please read [ask] and edit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just trying this, and it works
`conn = psycopg2.connect(host="192.168.13.10",database="postgres", port="5432", user="postgres", password="potatona1")`
    `cursor = conn.cursor()`

```
FullChar = 'CEFLMPRTVWXYK0123456789'
total = 1000
count = 10
count = int(count)
entries = []
bcd = ""
flg = ""
rll = ""
```

`def inputDatabase(data):
        postgres_insert_query = """INSERT INTO unique_code(unique_code, barcode, flag, roll) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)"""
        cursor.executemany(postgres_insert_query, data)
        conn.commit()`

```
for i in range(5):
    for x in range(total):    # banyaknya code yang di print
        unique_code = ''.join(random.sample(FullChar, count - 1))
        unique_code = ''.join(random.sample(unique_code, len(unique_code)))

        entry = (unique_code, bcd, flg, rll)
        entries.append(entry)

    inputDatabase(entries)
    print(i)

count = cursor.rowcount
print (count, "Record inserted successfully into mobile table")
```